# Which android tab supports v4L2 with USB host functionality?

Tags: android

I need to know the names of some android tablets with V4L2 support & host functionality. Suppose if plug in an USB camera.
Can anyone name any tablets with such functionality ?

Thanks a many lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following as working:

- Acer A500 and A501
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1" (original version)
- Evorea 7" tablet
- Ampe A10 quad-core 10.1" tablet

I'm testing the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 2 right now and it doesn't seem to be working, but it might be a problem with the USB adapter I'm using.